# How can I use Lagrange multipliers (multiple constraints)/(with a vector constraint λ)

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

To show that the pseudoinverse solution based on this form H^+ = H^T(HH^T)^−1 .
can be derived by finding the shortest image vector f that satisfies the imaging equation. In other words, show that the solution to the problem
*f*(hat)=argmin1/2*f*^*Tf*
s.t  g = Hf
is the pseudoinverse solution  *f*(hat) = H^T(HH^T)^−1g

Comment: Please use MathJax to formulate your question. Text equations are so boomer.

Comment: OP, What is the hat in your argument? What set is the argmin taken over? Your question is poorly formulated.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to understand your question and notation. Please formulate your question properly and also provide some context and what you've tried so far